# Return from nested condition, for loop, try/catch block in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, nested, return, try-catch

I've got a nested block of a condition, a for loop and try/catch block to return a tuple:

```
  val (a, b) = {
    if (...) {
      for (...) {
        try {
          getTuple(conf)
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable => println(...)
        }
      }
      sys.exit
    } else {
      try {
        getTuple(userConf)
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => println(...); sys.exit
      }
    }
  }
```

If the `if` condition matches I would like to try x different `conf` configurations. When `getTuple` throws an exception, try the next one. When `getTuple` does not throw an exception, fill the tuple with the result. `getTuple` returns the tuple `(a,b)`.

Problem: However, the `for` loop does not exit when `getTuple` does *not* throw an exception. I also tried `break` but that does not work as it should return the tuple and not just exit the `for` loop.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: scala only has `for` comprehension. In infinite loop is near impossible. I your looping through a infinite Stream, maybe! Second the sys.exit call in the if statement after evaluating the for comprehension is misplaced!

Comment: The for loop is not infinite, it only loops a couple of times.

Comment: I don't get it. *The for loop is not infinite* (comment) and *However, the for loop never exits* (question) seems somewhat contradicting...

Comment: Sorry about that, I rephrased that part.

Comment: @str could you please post an approximation of your `for` loop from which you get the the configurations to test? It would help in finding the correct way to break from the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of throwing Exception, getTuple should evaluate as a `Option[Tuple2[T,U]]`, it has more meaning and does not break the flow of the program.

This way, you can have a for like this:

```
val tuples: List[Option[Tuple2[T,U]] = for {
  c <- configs
} yield getTuple(c)

val firstWorkingConfig: Option[Tuples2[T,U]] = tuples.flatten.headOption

// Exit the program if no config is okay
firstWorkingConfig.getOrElse {
  sys.exit
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would prefer `configs.toStream.map(c => getTuple(c))` instead of the for loop here.

Comment: Good idea, I thought of Streams but did not came up quickly with a solution so I went by the for comprehension ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use more functional features of Scala instead of dealing with loops and exceptions.

Suppose we have a function that throws an exception on some inputs:

```
def myfn(x: Double): Double =
  if (x < 0)
    throw new Exception;
  else
    Math.sqrt(x);
```

We can either refactor it to return `Option`:

```
def optMyfn(x: Double): Option[Double] =
  if (x < 0)
    None;
  else
    Some(Math.sqrt(x));
```

Or if we don't want to (or cannot modify the original code), we can simply wrap it using `Exception.Catcher`:

```
def optMyfn(x: Double): Option[Double]
  = scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch.opt(myfn(x));
```

Now let's have a sequence of numbers and we want to find the first one on which the function succeeds:

```
val testseq: Seq[Double] = Seq(-3.0, -2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0);
```

We can use Scala's functional features to apply the function to all the elements and find the first `Some` result as

```
testseq.toStream.map(optMyfn _).flatten.headOption
```

It'd work as well without using `toStream`, but we'd call `optMyfn` unnecessarily on all the element, instead of just those we need to find the first successful result - streams make the computation [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

(Another option would be to use [views](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html), like

```
testseq.view.map(optMyfn _).collectFirst({ case Some(x) => x })
```

.)

Answer (score 1):

The `sys.exit` call is kinda misplaced in the `if` statement. It should be inside the `catch` clause to allow for a return of tupe if try is successful.

Comment: When an exception is thrown, it should just try again and not exit. It should only exit when all possibilities where tried (i.e. leaving the `for` loop) without success. So the `sys.exit` is at the correct position.

Comment: The second one yes the first one... No. Also the for loop will continue to loop through even after finding a configuration, A `list` of type `tuple`s will be the result whereas the expected  type is `Tuple2`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop until you get a working tuple a `while` loop makes more sense. The semantics of a for loop is to evalute the body *for all* elements you are iterating. Since your goal is to stop after the first which satisfies a condition, a while loop seems much more natural. Of course there would be some more functional alternatives, for instance:

- wrap your `getTuple` in an `Option`, where `None` corresponds to an exception.
- put the calls to `getTuple` in some iterable/traversable collection
- get the first element which is not `None`

While I was explaining the concept, [Romain Sertelon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086664/1804173) gave a nice example of the idea...

Comment: There is also a maximum number of tries, so a `for` loop makes sense. Also, the problem would not be different with a `while` loop.

Comment: A maximal number of tries is not a problem with a while loop, just extends your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to just wrap the whole block into a method and use return like:

```
  val (a: Type, b: Type) = setup(...)

  def setup(...) : (Type, Type) = {
    if (...) {
      for (...) {
        try {
          return getTuple(...)
        } catch {
          ...
        }
      }
      sys.exit
    } else {
      try {
        return getTuple(...)
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => println(...); sys.exit
      }
    }
  }
```

I think I should learn more basics of Scala, but that works now for the moment.

Thanks for your answers.